# Можно ли в MS SQL поменять вставляемые данные с помощью триггера?

Tags: триггер, sql-server

Например, вот моя табличка с тегами. Есть главный тег, "информационные технологии", а есть его псевдоним, "ит". Я хочу, чтобы при вставке в таблицу постов новой записи, помеченной тегом "ит" проверялось, есть ли он уже в таблице tags, и если есть, есть ли у него значение в поле real_id, и, если это так, вставлять в таблицу постов запись с полем tag_id=1, а не два.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Используйте instead of update триггер.